# How to convert pvr format to mp4 or avi?

Tags: video-conversion

At least I want to watch it on my desktop.

I tried softwares like hd video converter and npvr and nothing worked and I also did some deep research and I couldn't find anything.Please help me(BTH this pvr video was created using mt tv box recording)(Windows 10,64 bit)
This video was recorded using my [TV set up box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwxRE.jpg) recording tool.

Comment: Have you tried googling "pvr conconverter" (and your OS, which you forgot to mention here).

Comment: I tried everything

Comment: According to the "internet", much of the data is pretty well encrypted. The suggestion is you by a TV tuner card, connect the box to that, play back the show, and use software on your computer to capture the tuner card video data.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, "PVR" is a generic term. Please share more details about the file! What is its extension? (.pvr?) What device/software/... created it? How did it end up on your computer?

In general though, I'd suggest at least trying ffmpeg for conversion.
If you're on Windows, you can find builds at [ffmpeg.zeranoe.com](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). If you use Ubuntu or Debian, `sudo apt install ffmpeg` should do the trick, but YMMV.

After downloading, extract the files, open up a command prompt (or PowerShell) in the extracted `bin/` directory, and run `ffprobe -i your_filename_here` (you can drag a file into your command prompt or PowerShell window to expand it into a path) to have FFmpeg try and recognize the file. If it looks successful, you can try `ffplay` to play the file, or `ffmpeg -i your_filename_here -crf 25 -preset veryfast out.mp4` to (try to) convert it into H.264 MP4.

Comment: Sorry for my question.This video was recorded using my [TV set up box][1] recording tool.And I wanted to publish tv episodes on youtube 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwxRE.jpg